# Do I have to free a HV* created with newHV?

Tags: perl, memory-leaks, perl-xs

If I write some XS code with a hash that I never expect to return to perl, do I have to free it? If so, how?

The closest I've come up with is hv_undef, but that is only clearing out the contents of the hash, not the hash itself, from what I understand.

```
HV* hash = newHV();
...
use the hash
...
hv_undef(hash);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`newHV` (like `newSV`, `newAV`, etc.) sets the reference count of the newly created value to 1.  To free it, [you just need to decrement it to 0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Reference-Counts-and-Mortality).  There's no special function for that for HVs, so just use `SvREFCNT_dec`:

```c
HV* hash = newHV();
/*
 * use the hash
 */
SvREFCNT_dec((SV *) hash);
```

Comment: Super. I guess the part of HV as a subclass of SV was not working in my head. This works great.

Answer (score 7):

`newHV` returns an `HV` with a reference count (refcnt) of one, signifying your code's hold on that `HV`. When you're done with that `HV`, you must release your hold on it by decrementing its refcnt. There are three common ways of doing this.

1. Done with it here and now.

   ```
   SvREFCNT_dec((SV*)hv);
   // hv is no longer safe to use here.
   ```

   `AV` and `HV` are "subclasses" of `SV`.
2. Done with it after the caller has a chance to reference it. (Doesn't really apply to hashes.)

   ```
   return sv_2mortal(sv);
   ```
3. Transfer "ownership".

   ```
   rv = newRV_noinc((SV*)hv);
   ```

   That's short for

   ```
   rv = newRV((SV*)hv);
   SvREFCNT_dec((SV*)hv);
   ```

   Note that you must similarly release your hold on the `rv` when you're done with it, so you'll often see the following:

   ```
   return sv_2mortal(newRV_noinc((SV*)hv));
   ```